# Parse a page downloaded by a proxy

Tags: jquery

I'm downloading an external resource using a proxy on my server:

```
function retrieveOG(resource_url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/interne/asynch/fetchfeeds/FetchOG.aspx?resource=" + encodeURIComponent(resource_url),
        success: function (page) {
            var mypage = $page;
            console.log($page("meta[name='og:title']"));
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
```

basically, it send the url to my server, which download the page and return to the client the whole page. All of this because I need to catch the meta tags of a page.

But it says `ReferenceError: $page is not defined`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `page`?

Comment: overlooking the wood for all the trees? :)

Comment: Yep sorry, wrong copy & paste! But still I can't access to it as "DOM ELEMENT"

Comment: @undefined: the typo isn't the only problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty obvious really, `$page` is not defined. You have defined `page` instead.

I would suggest doing it like this:

```
success: function (page) {
    var $mypage = $(page);//convert your HTML string into a JQuery object
    console.log($mypage.filter("meta[name='og:title']").attr("content"));
}
```

That is making the assumption that `page` is an HTML string. It then converts that html string into a JQuery object called `$mypage`. This JQuery object can then be queried.

Because there is no parent wrapper element, we must use `filter` instead of `find` in this instance.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/CbBaV/)

---

If you want to use `find` instead, you can wrap the page in a parent tag like this:

```
var $mypage = $("<html/>").append(page);
console.log($mypage.find("meta[name='og:title']").attr("content"));
```

Comment: Yes, what I want to do. But, it says now `TypeError: $mypage is not a function`

Comment: @markzzz: Sorry, just spotted that too. I have edited, try that

Comment: @markzzz: I am not sure if `.html()` is what you want though. How much of the meta tag do you want? can you show an example of what you want to log?

Comment: `$mypage` now contains elements of the `body` element. As far as I know the query should return an empty set.

Comment: of course it would, that because the body element is in the `page` html. Please update you question and describe exactly what output you need

Comment: In the downloaded page-string there is `<meta name="og:title" content="How can I check classes that ends with?" />`. I want `How can I check classes that ends with?`

Comment: now is "undefined"... but there is, because if I print the content of page

Comment: @markzzz: I am just testing a fiddle, I get undefined too which is strange. Just trying to work it out now

Comment: Have you read my previous comment? Browsers only render elements of the body element, I had this problem in the past, finally I used a hidden input for storing meta/title elements' values.

Comment: @undefined: But in this case the browser isn't expected to render anything. We are only using JQuery to query a html string